# NavigationBar Right Button Problem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation bar in my app. The below pictures are in the order of navigation.

Problem I have is, on clicking the "Main" button , I am able to perform the action and goto the required screen , but the navigation bar does not look like the first on (with Menu as left button). Instead it look like 4th image. How to make it look like first image so that I can make the user to navigate to "Menu" screen by clicking menu button ?. Thanks for the help …!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you may have pushed the first view controller (The one from screenshot 1) when clicking on main which is why you see "lens" in the back button.  That back button takes the title of the previous view controller in the stack.  What you want to do is pop to the first view controller when they click on Main using either popToRootViewController or popToViewController:animated

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction. Here is what I did

for (UINavigationController *v in self.navigationController.viewControllers){
        
        UIViewController *vc = v;
        
        
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[FeatureSelectViewController class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:v animated:YES];
        }
        
        
    }

Everything works as expected…!!! Thanks again …!!!